# Pasar datos de Json a Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Como puedo extraer datos de json a javascript sin usar this como este ejemplo:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArr[0];
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo_array.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: podrías explicar mejor por favor por que indicas en tu publicación "sin usar this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu pregunta está mal formulada pero para recoger datos de un JSON con javascript el código que tienes es correcto, si deseas consultar luego esos datos lo mejor que guardes el JSON en un array te muestro un ejemplo.

```
var datos = []
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArr[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
            datos.push(myArr[i])
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo_array.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```